# jQuery Variable In Between Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I want to pass the following variable like so:

```
var $headerHeight = jQuery("#header").outerHeight() - jQuery("#header .main-menu").outerHeight();

jQuery(this).find('nav').attr('style', 'margin-top:' + $headerHeight + '!important');
```

It's obviously used in the wrong syntax; I just can't figure out how to use it correctly. The jQuery ".css" function isn't an option because it has to have the "!important" declaration. How can I pass `$headerHeight` in the above example?

Comment: !important is a sign of failure. See: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Comment: Because of the way css specificity works, you shouldn't need to use `!important` on an inline-style, inline styles override stylesheets unless the declaration is using `!important`. If that's the case, the correct fix would be to fix the css.

Comment: You need to add some pixels if you intend to use that as a string -> `+'px!important'`, however I do tend to agree, having to use important this way is a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: The reason I'm having to use "!important" is because I'm using the jQuery "slideToggle" function which adds a margin-top which I don't want as it moves the menu down as the height grows, I need the menu in a fixed place and for it to just slide down with height, my "!important" solution doesn't work the way I wanted anyway now I've added the "px" unit I forgot (thanks for that by the way, not sure how I forgot it), anyone got any ideas on a jQuery "slideToggle" alternative function which only slides down in height and not position? Cheers, Tom.

Comment: @Tom then i suggest instead using `$.animate`, it will result in much cleaner code than using slideDown with inline `!important`. slideDown's css changes will override your `!important` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var headerHeight = $("#header").outerHeight() - $("#header .main-menu").outerHeight();

    jQuery(this).find('nav').attr('style', 'margin-top:' +headerHeight+'px ' + '!important');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a unit to the property value.  (probably `px`)

Comment: Thanks for this, if you're interested in helping a dude out see the comment above, if not cheers anyways! Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You're fixing the wrong problem. Instead of un-doing a change that slideToggle does, simply don't use slideToggle.

```
$(myelement).animate({
    height: "200px" // or whatever your target height is, calculated or static.
},500/*duration*/);
```